# Metatrader 5 closes after initialization

Tags: python, authentication, initialization, shutdown, metatrader5

I'm trying to initialize Metatrader 5 with Python and have it login. All seems to work fine. However, after it's launched metatrader and logged in to the trader account, Metatrader crashes and shuts down.

Am I missing something?

```
import MetaTrader5 as mt5

if not mt5.initialize(login=12345, server="Server_Name",password="123456"):
    print("initialize() failed, error code =",mt5.last_error())
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The script works, but for some reason MetaTrader crashes immediately after the script has finished.

Comment: is this a script problem or a metatrader problem ?